# Should i change/alter xjc generated java files?

Tags: java, jaxb

Should i alter the xjc generated .java files. This is not about how to do it.

let's say, I have a xjc generated file A.java with method 
`getField()` and 
`setField(String s)`.

I want the xml generated with a specific format. The code is calling `a.setField("mystring")` from multiple places.

Two ways to achieve it: 
i. format the string before passing it to `a.setField`. but this will change at multiple places.
ii. Alter generated setField method from A.java to format the field.

Which will be better design choice considering the fact that A.java will be regenerated on next xjc run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with generated files i recommend to just extend the generated files and work with the extensions. Then you are free to regenerate the files at any time and just make minor adjustments to the extending files.